# Global .gitignore within vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, gitignore

Steps below work fine when I want to ignore a file globally in Linux however when I SSH into vagrant and run `git status` I can still see `.idea/` as "Untracked". What should I do in order to help vagrant picking  up these global settings?

I placed `.idea/` in `.gitignore` file as created below.

```
bc@bc:~$ sudo nano .gitignore
bc@bc:~$ git config --global core.excludesfile /home/bc/.gitignore
```

Comment: Do you ssh into vagrant with the `inanzzzz` account?

Comment: Yes I do so :`inanzzz@path/to/project/folder/: vagrant ssh` and `cd /vagrant`

Comment: Do you have a `~inanzzz/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: I only have `id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts`

Comment: Did you do the `git config --global core.excludesfile /home/inanzzzz/.gitignore` in the ssh session, or *before* doing the ssh?

Comment: Yes I did just before SSH (not in ssh) but I've just destroyed the vagrant so I'll try it again in a few hours and give an update.

Comment: Ok. When you do, can you check if that setting is still there once you start the ssh session? `ssh` and then type `git config --global core.excludesfile`, to see if it still reference `/home/inanzzzz/.gitignore`.

Comment: OK, when I run `vagrant@mydev:/vagrant$ git config --global core.excludesfile` I get nothing.

Comment: That is the issue then. A global config is under $home. But what is $home when you ssh? Can you do an echo $home ?

Comment: It is `/home/vagrant` while in vagrant and `/home/inanzzzz` for the other

Comment: Could you try and set your core.exclude file during the ssh session?  That should update the correct global config file

Comment: I replaced `inanzzzz` part with `vagrant` as seen in my OP and repeated the steps again then SSHed into vagrant and run `git status` but the `.idea/` is still visible. I did same thing while I'm in vagrant session as you said but no change.

Comment: Just for testing, can you go in that git repo, and add `.idea` in a `.gitignore` done in the same folder as the `.idea/` folder? Just to check that a local gitignore (local to the repo) works.

Comment: Yes it works like that.

Comment: In case it makes any difference, can you remove the rule you just added in the local `.gitignore`, and add `/.idea/` (instead of `.idea`) in the global one?

Comment: I'll continue tomorrow cos time to leave work for today. I'll update you tomorrow. Thanks for today!

Comment: @VonC - Solution is yours so If you answer to this question with: run `vagrant@mydev:/vagrant$ sudo nano /home/vagrant/.gitignore_global` Place `.idea/` line in the file then save/exit then `vagrant@mydev:/vagrant$ git config --global core.excludesfile /home/vagrant/.gitignore_global`. Then I can accept your answer. Some didn't like my answer as solution for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is where git will look for the global config in the ssh session: it will be in **`/home/vagrant`**.

Hence the solution (initially detailed by [inanzzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1251684/inanzzz)):

```
vagrant@mydev:/vagrant$ sudo nano /home/vagrant/.gitignore_global
```

Place an `.idea/` line in the file then save/exit.

```
vagrant@mydev:/vagrant$ git config --global core.excludesfile /home/vagrant/.gitignore_global
```